# How to change an instance attribute of an object by calling a statically called method in nested classes

Tags: python, class, nested

I want the Inner class to change an instantiated object (o)'s attribute, in this case, "some_var"; o.some_var.

I already tried searching on Google and stackoverflow about nested classes and how an inner class could access the outer class attributes. I changed the parameters taken by the inner class, like the instantiated object (self), to no effect.

```py
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_var = 1
        self.Inner = Inner()

    class Inner:
        def print_some_var(self):
            print("I'm Inner's method, printing:", self.some_var)

        def change_some_var(self, n):
            self.some_var = n

o = Outer()

print("Printing directly.", o.some_var)
o.Inner.print_some_var()
o.Inner.change_some_var(5)
o.Inner.print_some_var()
```

I need two things from this code, both based on the Inner class having access to the Outer class, and also on changing/reading it, by statically calling it (the Inner class) and change the Outer class object attribute (some_var). Like:

1. change the Outer class object's some_var by calling the Inner class, like "o.Inner.change_some_var(5)".
2. print/read the Outer class object's some_var by also calling the Inner class statically inside of the instantiated object, like "o.Inner.print_some_var()".

Instead, the python interpreter throws me an exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nestedclasses.py", line 16, in <module>
    o.Inner.print_some_var()
  File "nestedclasses.py", line 8, in print_some_var
    print("I'm Inner's method, printing:", self.some_var)
AttributeError: 'Inner' object has no attribute 'some_var'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_var = 1
        self.inner = Inner(self)

class Inner:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def print_some_var(self):
        print("I'm Inner's method, printing:", self.parent.some_var)

    def change_some_var(self, n):
        self.parent.some_var = n

o = Outer()

print("Printing directly.", o.some_var)
o.inner.print_some_var()
o.inner.change_some_var(5)
o.inner.print_some_var()
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you a lot.